# Sending picture through intent and display into PDF

Tags: java, android

I have three Activities

1. Hobbies
2. Language
3. Add Photo

**What my goal:** I get value of the hobby and language activity and also photo one and send it to the other activity and with that knowledge i create PDF file

**Problem** since i have 3 activities if user first go to Hobby activity and fill fields and then go to the language activity and fill all fields and at the end user go to the photo activity and fetch the photo from phone media and then create PDF file by doing this way I get the data as well as picture in PDF .Here my code works perfect **USER SELECT PHOTO AT THE END AFTER FILLING DATA IN OTHER ACTIVITIES** but **Problem occur** when and if he selects image first and then fills data and create PDF what happens I only get data in my PDF no sign of picture !!

I wanna put all the code but that too much code

**Sending picture**

```
  private void getting_data_from_fields_and_sending_on_click_listner() {

    Intent i = new Intent (Add_Picture_Activity.this , Selecting_Activity.class) ;

    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
    resultBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100 , b);
    byte[] bytes = b.toByteArray();


    i.putExtra("UserImage" , bytes);


    startActivity(i);

}
```

**receiving Picture**

```
  public void gettingInfoFromTheAddPictureActivity() {

        bitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("UserImage");
        byte [] bytes = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("UserImage");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes , 0  , bytes.length);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100 , stream);


        userImage  = null ;
        try {

            userImage = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        }catch (Exception c){

        }
    }



  try {
            gettingInfoFromTheAddPictureActivity();
            userImage.scaleToFit(80 , 80);
            userImage.setAbsolutePosition(0,0) ;
            p.getDirectContent();
            document.add(userImage);
        }catch (Exception x){
        }
```

Comment: Instead of passing bitmap pass the local path of image and decode it as bitmap whenever needed . or you can use a Image loader library to load image efficiently .

Comment: can you point me how can i get the path of selected image from drive

Comment: Well if you are using a cloud URL as image . Then you should use Image Loader to load bitmap from URL . Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load . and Pass the URL between Components .

Comment: i am fetching image from the device i.e Gallery

Comment: hahaha . i though drive as google drive . Well it will also work in this case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some How i solved the problem 
First i get the path of the user selected image and store it in pref and then use that path to create a bitmap in other activity and then with the bitmap i load image to the PDF File ..

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri imageUri = data.getData( );
            picturePath = getPath( Add_Picture_Activity.this, imageUri );
            Log.d("Picture Path", picturePath);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have not select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
    }

 public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri ) {
        String result = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver( ).query( uri, proj, null, null, null );
        if(cursor != null){
            if ( cursor.moveToFirst( ) ) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( proj[0] );
                result = cursor.getString( column_index );
            }
            cursor.close( );
        }
        if(result == null) {
            result = "Not found";
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void getting_data_from_fields_and_sending_on_click_listner() {

        Intent sendingPicPath = new Intent (Add_Picture_Activity.this , Selecting_Activity.class);
       editor = pref.edit() ;
        editor.putString("IMAGEPATH" , picturePath);
        editor.apply();
        startActivity(sendingPicPath);

    }
```

on other activity

```
    String imagePath = user_image.getString("IMAGEPATH" ,"");


    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
```